# getting a substring from content based on tricky regular expression pattern with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

I have a paragraph and I want to get the 1st part of the paragraph over 100 characters and under 150 characters where I find the '.' (end of sentence). So basically I want to get the text with over 100 characters and under 150, but to not cut it in the middle of a sentence. I need to do this with Jquery.

e.g.

`<p id="post">Content here content here content here content here content here content here. More content</p>`

Comment: Have you searched jquery plugins? I've seen plugins with similar functionality (if not exactly), unfortunately I don't remember the names. If these plugins don't exactly meet your needs, they may be good points to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you, but you should post your code so we can see what we are working with

```
// get paragraphs, and filter it to match only ones greater than 100 in length
$('p').filter(function(){
  if ($(this).text().length > 100 && $(this).text().length < 150)
    return true
  else
    return false
  // get the `text` of the paragraph, and replace everything after a period after 100 words
}).text().replace(/(.{100,150})\..+$/,'$1')
```

regex: delimited by `/`, capture (`(...)`) any character (`.`) between 100 and 150 times (`{100,150}`) followed by (escaped `\`) `.` followed by any character `.` one or more times (`+`) followed by the end (`$`). Which captures the first characters up to a `.` between 100 and 150 chars.

---

Edit: In case it is useful to you...

This is not exactly the same as the question, but instead returns the string when it is shorter than the `start` value, or chops it on a `.` between `start` and `limit`, or just chops it at `limit` where there is no match.

```
/**
 * @returns string Text from inside matched element (or concatenated elements)
 *     but cute off after the start, and before the limit on any available `.`
 *     or returns short strings, or cuts off at limit where there is no match
 */
$.fn.cutNicely = function(start, limit){
    var regex = new RegExp( "(.{" + start + "," + limit + "}\\.).+$" )
    return this.text().substr(0,limit).replace(regex,'$1')
}

// usage:
$('p').cutNicely(80,150)
```

Comment: This is actually quite a useful and basic thing. I might make a general solution, and add it to my library. I think the interface should be `$(selector).chopNicely(100,150)` which will cut and return the text, always making it less than 150 chars (even if brutal cutting required), but will attempt to cut nicely anywhere appropriate after 100 chars.